# Issue with Jquery blur with apex

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle-apex

I am trying to do a simliar thing like this on Apex

[Jquery example NOT in apex](http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/validateform/)

The link above shows an example but it is `not` in apex.

Basically I want to validation a field as a user is typing and remove the error as soon as the field is correct.

I am using apex verion 4.0.

What I have done so far and it is not working as in I am not getting any error message even though I am trying to force an error.

On the page `HTML headers and Body Attribute` I have my css

```
`<style>
#error{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
#error ul{
    list-style: square;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#error ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
#error ul li strong{
    color: #e46c6d;
}
#error.valid ul li strong{
    color: #93d72e;
}

</style>`
```

and in javascript I have

```
`$(document).ready() {
var name = $("#P1_TEST");
};
<script>
function validateName(){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(p_t03.val().length < 4){
        p_t03.addClass("error");
                error_message("Must be than 3 letters!");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        p_t03.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
<script>
p_t03.blur(validateName);
p_t03.keyup(validateName);
</script>`
```

**Please note** that `p_t03` is the `P1_TEST` name. because on inspect element on chrome. `id="pP1_TEST" name=" p_t03"

On `Item`-> `P1_TEST` -> `HTML Form Element Attributes`. II have `onblur="validateName();"` which should check the jquery validation above.

This is my first time doing this on apex. I am too sure if I am doing the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JavaScript with this:

```
var name = $("#P1_TEST");

function validateName(){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(name.val().length < 4){
        name.addClass("error");
                error_message("Must be than 3 letters!");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        name.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    name.blur(validateName);
    name.keyup(validateName);
})
```

Why your code didn't work:

- `<script></script>` tags are not required if you're placing code in page attributes > JavaScript.
- `p_t03.blur();` is not correct syntax for calling JQuery.  `$('[name="p_t03"]').blur();` is what you need. For simplicity's sake, I used ID instead of name in my answer.

Best of luck with the rest of your project.